# Regenerate ctags TAGS file without freezing Emacs for a while?

Tags: projectile, ctags, async

When I'm currently in a large project and I call the command
`projectile-regenate-tags`, the project will be scanned by `ctags` and the tags will be stored in the `TAGS` file.

While all this action is progressing, Emacs will be unreachable until the tags generation is completed.

I know there are some attempts to make Emacs process asynchronously, or even
doing it in the background. My knowledge of concurrency is somewhat limited, so

I'm wondering if there is any way that I could call `projectile-regenerate-tags`
and while the tags file being processed, I can do further other things with
Emacs and the text? If so, what would be a good way to make it so?

Comment: Open a bug report.  This is not something you can fix by customizing an option.

Comment: Is it really a bug? I guess Emacs is waiting on input when it's done. Why do you consider it as a bug?

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` is, in spite of its name, also for enhancement requests. So if you don't get a good answer to your question here, then you might want to consider filing an enhancement request.

Comment: Could you maybe invoke the code that provides the behavior you need asynchronously, using emacslient or emacs in batch mode? Remember that you can invoke any program or shell script using, say, `&` in Dired.

Comment: It's a bug for projectile to do this synchronously, not for Emacs to do what it's told to.  There is no magical switch that makes every single operation in Emacs non-blocking, it's up to package authors to leverage its possibilities properly.  You may believe it's normal for a text editor to not ever hang up, but that's their authors respecting this very basic design assumption.

Comment: @wasamasa at your recommendation, I reported it to the Emacs development list as bug with `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: @wasamasa could I consider this issue as closed, by the way?

Comment: On a side note, if you use `global`/`gtags` instead of `ctags`, the `ggtags` package supports asynchronous update of the gtags using `global -u`. Updating gtags is also faster then ctags as it does differential updates. I use both `projectile` and `ggtags` but I never need to call `projectile-regenerate-tags` as `ggtags` does the job automatically for me, without me knowing that the tags are being updated.

Comment: @kaushalmodi interesting, could you tell more about how did you do that with automaticallly generation of tags with `ggtags` for projectile projects? Perhaps with a blog post or something? I would love to apply it in my Emacs projects.

Comment: @ReneFroger It's pretty straight-forward. If `some-prj` is your project root directory, `cd` to that directory and call `gtags` for the first time gtags creation. Then onwards, those tags will be auto updated by `ggtags`. You can manually update the tags from the terminal by running `global -u` (that's what `ggtags` runs asynchronously for you).

Comment: After figuring it out, it seems it's `ggtags.el` that does this. After enabled `gtags-mode`  in my project, then I had some problems to tell `helm-etgas-select` to use the tag file that's being used by `ggtags` instead of `ctags`. So I guess this is too much to handle in the comments section. I would love to see a blog post of something, because I like the concept behind automatic tag update.

Comment: @ReneFroger Sure, I will try to find some time to write it up. My [gtags config on gitub](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/1967df611445021747a2a1235ad21f1c283d2424/setup-files/setup-tags.el#L17-L81) is all the setup that would be required... Well, you will not even need half of that config as it is customized to my needs. I do not used helm but I believe that if you use gtags, probably [helm-gtags](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-gtags) is a better package. The only gtags package I need for auto update is [`ggtags`](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags).

Comment: @KaushalModi thanks! I was already looking around for gtags to install, but I couldn't find it, from your config I now understand I need `global`. :-)

Comment: @ReneFroger This is not an Emacs bug, but a projectile bug.  The Emacs team cannot do anything about Emacs to fix this issue with projectile (unless they invent the magic pill transforming synchronous code to equivalent asynchronous code), report it for projectile instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/redguardtoo/counsel-etags/blob/master/counsel-etags.el which originally called `aysnc-shell-command` to run shell command `ctags -e -R`.

Or else write your own implementation. Just three lines:

```
  (let* ((async-shell-command-buffer 'new-buffer)
         (display-buffer-alist '(("Async Shell Command" display-buffer-no-window))))
    (async-shell-command "ctags -e -R"))
```

The problem of `async-shell-command` is it will create a buffer and it can't notify the user when the tags file is generated. So here is a better version,

```
(defun counsel-etags-async-shell-command (command)
  "Execute string COMMAND and create tags file asynchronously."
  (let* ((proc (start-process "Shell" nil shell-file-name shell-command-switch command)))
    (set-process-sentinel
     proc
     `(lambda (process signal)
        (let* ((status (process-status process)))
          (when (memq status '(exit signal))
            (cond
             ((string= (substring signal 0 -1) "finished")
              (let* ((cmd (car (cdr (cdr (process-command process))))))
                (message "Tags file was created.")))
             (t
              (message "Failed to create tags file.\nerror=%s\ncommand=%s"
                       signal
                       ,command)))))))))

(counsel-etags-async-shell-command "ctags -e -R")
```